# 'npm start' command fails to run my Nodejs API and gives below error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I clone the project from GitLab -> install node_modules by "npm install -g" -> and run "npm start" command in terminal but it give some errors as below.

````
Error Cannot find module '../services/'
     Require stack:
      - /opt/projects/api_server_node/node_modules/ravepay/lib/rave.bvn.js
      - /opt/projects/api_server_node/node_modules/ravepay/index.js
      - /opt/projects/api_server_node/services/flutterwaveService.js
      - /opt/projects/api_server_node/controllers/flutterwaveController.js
      - /opt/projects/api_server_node/controllers/bookingController.js
      - /opt/projects/api_server_node/routes/booking.js
      - /opt/projects/api_server_node/index.js
  Error: Cannot find module '../services/'
    Require stack:
      - /opt/projects/api_server_node/node_modules/ravepay/lib/rave.bvn.js
      - /opt/projects/api_server_node/node_modules/ravepay/index.js
      - /opt/projects/api_server_node/services/flutterwaveService.js
      - /opt/projects/api_server_node/controllers/flutterwaveController.js
      - /opt/projects/api_server_node/controllers/bookingController.js
      - /opt/projects/api_server_node/routes/booking.js
      - /opt/projects/api_server_node/index.js
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1029:15)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:898:27)
   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
   at Object.<anonymous> 
(/opt/projects/api_server_node/node_modules/ravepay/lib/rave.bvn.js:2:22)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/projects/api_server_node/node_modules/ravepay/index.js:17:11)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/projects/api_server_node/services/flutterwaveService.js:16:17)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
at Object.<anonymous>   
(/opt/projects/api_server_node/controllers/flutterwaveController.js:28:20)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1 
npm ERR! bookadabra_api@1.0.0 start: `node ./index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bookadabra_api@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. The`enter code here`re is likely 
additional logging output above.```
````

**screeshot of the error (https://prnt.sc/vpykry)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Downgrade the `ravepay` module from 1.3.0 to 1.2.4, but do take time to read the **WARNING** paragraph below first.

The stack trace indicates that your issue is in the `ravepay` module. Trying to use a plain installation of `ravepay` resulted in a similar error to what you're seeing for every version of Node.js I tried (15.x, 14.x, 12.x, and 10.x--all the versions currently supported by the Node.js project at the time of this writing).

There's no information about Node.js version support for `ravepay`, or at least not that I can find as of this writing. However, looking at [their GitHub Action at the time of this writing](https://github.com/Flutterwave/ravepay-nodejs/blob/8d2ecb031e9b429d352dadedcef6367cf1e7bea4/.github/workflows/npm-publish.yml#L18) reveals that they use Node.js 12.x. But using 12.x didn't help.

The current version of `ravepay` is 1.3.0. Downgrading to 1.2.4 fixes the issue.

```
$ node -v
v15.3.0
$ npm -v
7.0.14
$ npm install ravepay      
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

added 61 packages, and audited 61 packages in 3s

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

2 high severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
$ npm ls ravepay
temp@ /Users/trott/temp
└── ravepay@1.3.0

$ node -e "require('ravepay')"
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../services/'
Require stack:
- /Users/trott/temp/node_modules/ravepay/lib/rave.bvn.js
- /Users/trott/temp/node_modules/ravepay/index.js
- /Users/trott/temp/[eval]
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:763:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/trott/temp/node_modules/ravepay/lib/rave.bvn.js:2:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/trott/temp/node_modules/ravepay/lib/rave.bvn.js',
    '/Users/trott/temp/node_modules/ravepay/index.js',
    '/Users/trott/temp/[eval]'
  ]
}
$ npm install ravepay@1.2.4

changed 1 package, and audited 61 packages in 1s

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

2 high severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
$ npm ls
temp@ /Users/trott/temp
└── ravepay@1.2.4

$ node -e "require('ravepay')"
$
```

**WARNING:** Even though that "fixes" the problem, those high severity audit warnings are not a reassuring sign on a credit card payment library. The `ravepay` module is relatively lightly used (227 weekly downloads at the time of this writing) and was last published a year ago (at the time of this writing). It is probably not much actively maintained and there is not evidence of a user base large enough to frequently surface simple issues like this and make solutions readily available to a user community. If you continue down this path, you may experience more problems like this. Be prepared.

EDIT: Oh yeah, and as [@Andrei Ionita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8043894/andrei-ionita) notes in their answer, don't install the project dependencies with the `-g` flag.

Comment: Okay, Thanks this solution works for me.
And yes for next time I will not install the project dependencies with the -g flag.
Thanks a lot once again!

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your globally installed packages and installing the project without the -g flag.

Comment: Yes, next time I will install node_modules without the -g flag.
Thank you!